# Update and delete calendar event without sending notification to attendees

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We need to update/delete an appointment event from a user calendar through MS Graph API **without** a change notification sent to the attendees. I'm unable to find any  option how to control this. In EWS API we were able to use options to control this.

```
appointment.Update(ConflictResolutionMode.AlwaysOverwrite, SendInvitationsOrCancellationsMode.SendToNone);
```

We found a workaround for the update. If we create an new empty `Event` object instance and set the ID of existing appointment and the custom properties data the notification is not sent. That is sufficient for our case. However we cannot use this for deleting.

Comment: were you abele to solve that?

Comment: @vir us, no we used the old EWS API specifically for that. However, the API might have been updated since then.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Microsoft Identity Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client/) nuget package and **OAuthCredentials** to keep using EWS like before. You have to grant **EWS.AccessAsUser.All** permission through Azure App Registration. This is the best way I found so far to remove EWS Basic Authentication.

```
string clientId = "Your Clinet Id";
string tenantId = "your Tenant Id";
string[] scopes = { "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS.AccessAsUser.All" };
Microsoft.Identity.Client.IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = Microsoft.Identity.Client.PublicClientApplicationBuilder.Create(clientId).WithTenantId(tenantId).Build();

System.Security.SecureString secureString = new System.Security.SecureString();
foreach (char ch in password)
     secureString.AppendChar(ch);

Microsoft.Identity.Client.AcquireTokenByUsernamePasswordParameterBuilder authBuilder = publicClientApplication.AcquireTokenByUsernamePassword(scopes, userName, secureString);
Microsoft.Identity.Client.AuthenticationResult result = await authBuilder.ExecuteAsync();

ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService
{
     Credentials = new OAuthCredentials(result.AccessToken)
};
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer, however, my question was not about the authentication. It is about API possibility to delete an event without notification being sent.

Comment: Would updating the event, by removing attendees from the attendees collection of the event object be a workaround?

Comment: EWS is being deprecated for Office 365.  New customers will be unable to use EWS starting September 30, 2022.  See https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/upcoming-api-deprecations-in-exchange-web-services-for-exchange/ba-p/2813925